# Gerrit - annotate patch-sets

Tags: git, gerrit

As I develop a change in Gerrit, I try to follow the workflow of pushing a new patch-set every time I reach a somewhat stable point.

It would be nice if I could annotate some patch-sets with messages like "create controller", "view uses variable", etc.

This way my patch-set history could help describe how the change came to be, thus providing some (at times) nice context.

I know that the files within a patch-set can be annotated (CodeReview), but is there a title or some other metadata that can be the "commit message" for the patch-set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make comments on your code during a review, they get associated with the latest patch set.

In the "history" section in the web ui, your comments are shown like this:

Patch Set 2: Code-Review+1
(2 comments)

This basically solves my initial query.